# How to correctly deploy ASP MVC Net Code 3.1 project into a subfolder of apache?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, apache

How to correctly deploy ASP MVC Net Code 3.1 project into a subfolder of apache (CentOS 7)?

Apache's default folder is `/var/www/html` and I want to deploy it in `/var/www/html/myapp`, so I can expect to see my app on the internet from **`https://example.com/myapp`**

All of the files (includes all folders inside the wwwroot) are now deployed in myapp folder, but it has the wrong address, I got 404 when my app trying to get all of the .css files .. like this one below:

```
GET https://example.com/css/style.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

GET https://example.com/vendor/bars.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

**it should go to https://example.com/myapp/css/style.min.css**

what I missed?

#### Startup.cs

```
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
      FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
      "wwwroot/vendor")),
    });
```

#### Program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
          webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
         .UseUrls("http://127.0.0.1:5000");
    });
```

#### httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin info@example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Location /myapp/>
      ProxyPass http://localhost:5000/
      ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:5000/
      Require all granted
    </Location>
```

#### Kestrel

```
 [Unit]
 Description=.NET Web Application on Linux
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/html/myapp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/html/myapp/myapp.dll
Restart=always

RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=root
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

TimeoutStopSec=90

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

as it is too big to post curl result here, I give some:

I run **curl http://localhost:5000**

#### Some of Curl Result

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home Page | mytest</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
    family=Open+Sans&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,500;1,500&display=swap" 
    rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/@coreui/icons/css/free.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/@fortawesome/fontawesome- 
 free/css/all.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
```

[image: Inside Web App Folder]

[image: Inside the Webroot Folder]

Comment: How have you set-up Apache to host ASP.NET Core? Please share your `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` files.

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, why are you using Apache instead of Nginx?

Comment: Are you at-least able to connect directly to the Kestrel server (i.e. without going through Apache)?

Comment: do you mean I go to the server and run locally like http://localhost:5000? if so, I can't because it is cloud hosted

Comment: I have tried to move all folders in wwwroot to /var/www/html (this is DocumentRoot folder)  it works properly, it looks like still using default DocumentRoot folder for accessing the contents

Comment: What does "cloud hosted" mean in this context? Why can't you open a shell in the server and test it using `wget` or `curl`? If you're on AWS then you should be using Nginx instead of Apache anyway, and if you're on Azure then you should use Azure's built-in support for hosting .NET Core applications - and if you're being forced to use Oracle Cloud then run away as fast as you can...

Comment: I use Alibaba cloud, ok noted, yes I am able to run wget http://localhost:5000 or curl http://localhost:5000